# Beginner beamer question: how to add two different citations in IEEE style on two separate pages

Tags: beamer, citing

I just started using Beamer

I have an extremely simple Beamer file

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\title[Your Short Title]{Your Presentation}
\author{You}
\institute{Where You're From}
\date{Date of Presentation}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  Citation 1 Goes here
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
    Citation 2 Goes here
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I have two citations in a file called "Citations.bib"

```
@ARTICLE{5756675, 
author={H. Borhan and A. Vahidi and A. M. Phillips and M. L. Kuang and I. V. Kolmanovsky and S. Di Cairano}, 
journal={IEEE Transactions on Control Systems Technology}, 
title={MPC-Based Energy Management of a Power-Split Hybrid Electric Vehicle}, 
year={2012}, 
volume={20}, 
number={3}, 
pages={593-603}, 
keywords={closed loop systems;electric machines;energy management systems;hybrid electric vehicles;machine control;nonlinear control systems;optimal control;predictive control;time-varying systems;power-split hybrid electric vehicle;MPC-based energy management;parallel hybrid vehicle architectures;series hybrid vehicle architectures;planetary gear set;electric machines;combustion engine;near optimal energy management strategy;nonlinear control problem;constrained optimal control problem;cost functions;model predictive control strategies;system operating points;closed-loop high-fidelity model;multiple standard drive cycles;fuel economy;commercial Powertrain System Analysis Toolkit software;linear time-varying MPC;Hybrid electric vehicles;Mathematical model;Engines;Biological system modeling;Torque;Energy management;Batteries;Energy management;hybrid electric vehicle (HEV);linear time-varying model predictive control (LTV-MPC);MPC;nonlinear MPC;power-split HEV}, 
doi={10.1109/TCST.2011.2134852}, 
ISSN={1063-6536}, 
month={May},}

@ARTICLE{4497237, 
author={A. N. Venkat and I. A. Hiskens and J. B. Rawlings and S. J. Wright}, 
journal={IEEE Transactions on Control Systems Technology}, 
title={Distributed MPC Strategies With Application to Power System Automatic Generation Control}, 
year={2008}, 
volume={16}, 
number={6}, 
pages={1192-1206}, 
keywords={closed loop systems;control engineering computing;distributed algorithms;distributed control;iterative methods;large-scale systems;power generation control;predictive control;distributed model predictive control;power system automatic generation control;large-scale networked control system;distributed MPC algorithm;closed-loop stability;intermediate termination;centralized model predictive control;iterative method;Power system control;Power systems;Automatic generation control;Power system modeling;Automatic control;Control systems;Predictive models;Predictive control;Control system synthesis;Large-scale systems;Automatic generation control;distributed model predictive control;power system control}, 
doi={10.1109/TCST.2008.919414}, 
ISSN={1063-6536}, 
month={Nov},}
```

I want to add these citations. One of each page. Since each of these references is from IEEEXplore, I would like to cite them in IEEE style (something like IEEEtran)

But I am not sure what commands I should use to incorporate the "Citation.bib" file into the Beamer file.

Can someone please help me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE! As you are using a bibliography database, you need to make it known to the document. One way is to add a frame with the references

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\title[Your Short Title]{Your Presentation}
\author{You}
\institute{Where You're From}
\date{Date of Presentation}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  Citation 1 Goes here \cite{5756675}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
    Citation 2 Goes here \cite{4497237}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{References}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{Citations}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

compile your tex file with `pdflatex <myfile>` (say), run `bibtex <myfile>` and then run `pdflatex <myfile>` twice to get the citations in.